# How to use PyTorch's torchaudio in Android?

Tags: android, pytorch

Starting from [here](https://pytorch.org/mobile/android/), I downloaded the tutorial project and got it to build and run. Then I tried adding this to the project's app build.gradle (after upping the pytorch version to 1.5.0):

```
implementation 'org.pytorch:pytorch_android_torchaudio:1.5.0'
```

And I got this error:

```
Could not find org.pytorch:pytorch_android_torchaudio:1.5.0.
```

Anyone else had any luck getting PyTorch's torchaudio to work in Android?

Comment: The docs said that the latest version is `1.4.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this answer from [here](https://github.com/pytorch/audio/issues/408#issuecomment-665052963):

> There is no android package dedicated for torchaudio. You build your model or pipeline in Python, then dump it as a Torchscript file, then load it from your app and run it with Torchscript runtime. Please refer to the following.

> https://pytorch.org/mobile/home/

> https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/Intro_to_TorchScript_tutorial.html